# PHP scoping and global

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```php
<html>
<body>
    <h1><?isFoo();?></h1>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$foo_app_cookie_val = "foo";

function isFoo() {
    global $foo_app_cookie_val;
    echo "in isFoo: '$foo_app_cookie_val'<br/>";
    return isApp($foo_app_cookie_val);
}
?>
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
isFoo: ''
```

Why aren't I seeing the actual value of $foo_app_cookie_val?

Comment: `$foo_app_cookie_val` is undefined by the time `isFoo()` is called.

Comment: right. yo uneed to define these things before calling hem. you are running <?isFoo(); ?> above. also change that to <?php isFoo(); ?>

Comment: note that <? as a opening tag is deprecated, use <?php

Comment: @GertB. I don't see anything about deprecation here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php.

Comment: @vbo ok, maybe a bad choice of words, but it would be better to change it

Comment: @GertB. Found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$foo_app_cookie_val` is being set to `foo` *after* `<h1><?isFoo();?></h1>` is output. Change the script to:

```
<?php
$foo_app_cookie_val = "foo";

function isFoo() {
    global $foo_app_cookie_val;
    echo "in isFoo: '$foo_app_cookie_val'<br/>";
    return isApp($foo_app_cookie_val);
}
?>
<html>
<body>
    <h1><?isFoo();?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `**facepalm**` I'm too used to languages that don't take declaration order into consideration :(

Answer (score 4):

`isFoo()` is being called before you've set the value of `$foo_app_cookie_val`. Try moving the large block of PHP code to the top of the file, like this:

```
<?php
$foo_app_cookie_val = "foo";

function isFoo() {
    global $foo_app_cookie_val;
    echo "in isFoo: '$foo_app_cookie_val'<br/>";
    return isApp($foo_app_cookie_val);
}
?>
<html>
<body>
    <h1><?isFoo();?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Where the function is actually declared doesn't matter. What matters is where you call the function in relation to setting the global variable.